# Using MPEG-DASH with encrypted video, how do I keep my encryption keys a secret?

Tags: security, encryption, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I need to make sure a user viewing a video on my site can't get a hard copy of it (unless he captures the screen which I can't prevent).

I'm looking into MPEG-DASH as a solution using Common Encryption (CENC).
I understand there is a license server that should verify the client before he gets the keys. I'm not quite sure if it's a server I setup or something public I use.

But how do I make sure an attacker can't get the keys from inside the browser somehow, download all the m4s chunks, decrypt them with the key he got from the browser and merge them?

If the player on the browser is supposed to decrypt each m4s file, it means it uses the key for each file which means it stores the key somewhere in the memory. Can't an attacker use the developer tools to step into the decryption code and take the descryption key?

Is there's some protection mechanism I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the job of the DRM vendor. The key is sent encrypted from the license server and decrypes the video inside the CDM in a protected environment. Look up widevine and play ready. If you do this yourself without a vendor, you must have the user install your CMD.

Comment: I'm planning on using widevine and already read about it. I was just concerned with how secure it is. Is the content decryption mode some kind of a black box an attacker can't get into? Does it get the encrypted key, uses the LA for decryption and I can be sure no-one will see the decrypted key?

Comment: Yes, it is a black box. No, nobody can get they key. Widevine is used by all major content companies on the internet, and has not been broken.